# Windows batch programming: Getting data of some command into some variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hello I want to collect output of following command into some variable.How can I do that?

```
type somefile.txt | find /v "irritating string"
```

Actually I want to write the output of above command to some other file in some other folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command may produce multiple lines of output. Windows batch does not have a convenient method to capture multiple lines of command output into a single variable. The FOR /F command can be used to process each line individually, at which point you could concatenate each line into a single variable (up to the ~8191 byte value length limit), or you could create an array of variables.

Type `FOR /?` or `HELP FOR` from a command prompt for more info about the FOR command.

But since you want to really capture the output in a file, the solution is exceedingly easy.

If you want to create a new file

```
type somefile.txt | find /v "irritating string" >"c:\somePath\newFile.txt"
```

If you want to append the output to an existing file

```
type somefile.txt | find /v "irritating string" >>"c:\somePath\existingFile.txt"
```

If the file does not exist yet, it will be created.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.Can you tell me what to do if I want the output file to be in some other folder,not in current directory?

Comment: @RajatSaxena - Simply prefix the output file name with the path to your folder. I've updated the answer with that trivial change. The quotes are there in case the path includes spaces.

Comment: Please don't mind but what if the directory in which this new file will be,is dynamically generated using the same script?How to specify the path then?